# parsing date IETF RFC 3339 in php

Tags: php, parsing, datetime

could anyone please explain how to parse date in IETF RFC 3339  in php, in most convenient method. an example of date in the above format is : 2011-03-14T06:25:22+0000

thanks!!

Comment: I'd say `new DateTime('2011-03-14T06:25:22+0000');`

Answer (score 1):

At least as of PHP 5.3, that format is natively supported by [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date_create`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php).  Using a DateTime from the PHP interactive shell:

```
php > $d = date_create('2011-03-14T06:25:22+0000');
php > echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
2011-03-14 06:25:22
php > echo $d->getTimezone()->getName();
+00:00
```

You'll probably want to read up on [all of the formats these two functions support](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Answer (score 0):

Using [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) ...

```
<?php
    // source date
    $source = strtotime('2011-03-14T06:25:22+0000');

    // remove this line to use your server's local time
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    // parse and print
    echo date('Y-m-d h:i.s A O', $source);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
2011-03-14 06:25.22 AM +0000
```